# How could I return a list of integers and duplicated integers that a maximum number of duplications is two in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of integers call Integerlist, and I want to return a list of integers and duplicated integers that a maximum number of duplications is two.

My input:

```
def function(numList):
    blank = []
    for x in numList:
        if x not in blank:
            blank.append(x)
        else:
            None

    result = blank
    return result

Integerlist = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,1,2,3,3]
print(function(Integerlist))
```

My output:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

But I want it to have only one more integer if the input have more than one integer like my desired output.

My desired output is:

`[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,1,3]`

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count the number of occurrences in the list before you append the value.

```py
def function(numList):
    blank = []
    for i in numList:
        if blank.count(i) < 2: blank.append(i)
    return blank
    
Integerlist = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,1,2,3,3]
print(function(Integerlist)) # [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want a function that receives a list of integers as input and returns a list that is the same as the input, *except* that any integers appearing more than twice in the input appear only twice in the output. Correct?

So you need a way to keep track of how many times each number has appeared in the input list. I recommend using a dictionary for this (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) for an introduction to Python dictionaries if you aren't familiar).

Your logic might look something like this (in pseudocode):

```
initialize dictionary called counts
initialize list called result
For every element in the input:
   if element doesnt exist as a key in counts yet, add it and set the value to 0 
   increment counts[element] by one 
   if counts[element] is less than 3:
      add element to result
return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a running count of the numbers already seen using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instance:

```
>>> numList = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,1,2,3,3]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter()
>>> result = []
>>> for num in numList:
...     if counter[num] >= 2:
...         continue
...     counter[num] += 1
...     result.append(num)
... 
>>> result
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 3]
```

This is more efficient than counting in `result` directly - it's *O(1)* average time complexity to look up in a `Counter` vs *O(n)* for [`list.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).